# MODBUS-tk Read floating point values from slave in the master

Tags: python-3.x, tk-toolkit, modbus, modbus-tcp, modbus-tk

I have created modbus slave to write data to the registers.
I am able to write both float values and integer values from the slave side.

In the modbus master I am able to access only the integer values but not able to read float values.

I went through this https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/issues/72 but that didn't solve my problem.

For the integer values reading I can use the below code and read the values.

```
master = modbus_tcp.TcpMaster()
master.set_timeout(time_out_period)
result = master.execute(slave = 100, function_code = 3 , starting_address = 0, quantity_of_x = 25)
```

But for the float values I used both the above and below code.

```
master = modbus_tcp.TcpMaster()
master.set_timeout(time_out_period)
result = master.execute(slave = 100, function_code = 3 , starting_address = 0, quantity_of_x = 25 , data_format='>f')
```

I get error while reading the float as,

> unpack requires a bytes object of length 4

Comment: what is the float value you are trying to write ?

Answer (score 0):

The quantity of x should be a multiple of 2. Because the float requires two 16 bit registers or words so if you want 25 it should be 50.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to provide the correct data format reflective of how many **individual** `float` values(below are big endian) are trying to be unpacked;

## 1 float

```
logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 0, 2, data_format='>f'))
```

## 2 floats

```
logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 0, 4, data_format='>ff'))
```

## 3 floats

```
logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 0, 6, data_format='>fff'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, using Numpy.
For example:

```
import numpy as np

# Sample registers to read
start_address = 0
items = 10
# Get the reply from slave
reply = master.execute(1, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, start_address, items*2)
# Convert the reply to Numpy array of type int16
d16 = np.array(reply, dtype=np.int16)
# Convert to an array of type float32
f32 = d16.view(dtype = np.float32)
```